# failed to compile .'Greeting' is not defined in react-router 3

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router 3 and I got this error which I couldn't rectify.Here is the error 
 Line 9:  'Greeting' is not defined in routes.js .
Here is my routes.js file .

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import App from './App';
const Greeting =()=>{
  return <div> Hey Greeting </div>;
};
export default(
   <Route path="/" component={App}>
   <Route path="greet" component={Greeting}/>
   </Route>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your return statement, wrap the HTML syntax in parenthesis like this:

```
return (<div> Hey Greeting </div>);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import App from './App';
import Greeting from './Greeting';

export default () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={App} />
        <Route path="greet" component={Greeting}/>
     </Route>
   </div>
  );
);
```